# Разбить график на тренды

Tags: математика, статистика, графики

Нужен способ найти три тренда на графике, визуально они показаны на втором скриншоте. Какие математические модели могут помочь их найти?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В теории временных рядов таких алгоритмов и даже подходов к решению задачи - достаточно много.
Основы описаны в книгах и даже учебниках по Теории временных рядов и Эконометрике. Перечислять их тут особого смысла нет.

Общая идея заключается в том, что-бы найти такие участки данных, в которых параметры модели, описывающие поведение объекта, статистически значимо отличались между собой. Начиная от тривиальных методов типа t-Стьюдента, СuCum или ANOVA  на скользящих окнах, до более продвинутых и сложных методов, основанных на моделях Хольта-Винтерса, ARIMA и пр. Мне встречались попытки решить задачу и методами, относящимися к DataMining - кластеризация, классификация и пр. В общем, все это называется "сегментация временного ряда", а в немножко другой интерпретации - "Change poitn detection".  Лет 20 назад  подобная задача изучалась (правда, на достаточно примитивном уровне )и в теории надежности.
Думаю, что и ссылки на научные статьи по теме тут давать тоже тоже  бессмысленно.

А далее каждый исследователь ищет для своих данных наиболее адекватный метод, т.е. такой метод, который наиболее точно учитывает природу и особенности поведения объектов именно в его предметной области. В том числе и в финансах

Comment: Спасибо за наводки!